# PHP split array based on value duplicated

Tags: php, arrays, split

Here is an example array I want to split:

```
(1,2,3,4,5,0,6,7,0,8,9,10,11,12,0)
```

How do I split it in 3 arrays like this?

```
(1,2,3,4,5,0) (6,7,0) (8,9,10,11,12,0)
```

Comment: It's not obvious from your question... why does it split where it does?

Comment: Yes please provide some more information, your question doesn't show any duplicate value to split at?

Comment: Where's the duplication part?

Comment: if my array (1,2,3,4,5,0,6,7,0,8,9,10,11,12,0)

how to split array by 0 to be (1,2,3,4,5,0) (6,7,0) (8,9,10,11,12,0)

Comment: @user3110422 What if there's more than one duplication e.g. ``(1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4)`` heres ``1,2,3,4`` are duplicate too. or this won't happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution. (Author said he wants to split at '0' instead of duplicate values)

```
function split_array_by_duplicate_values($a, $duplicate = 0)
{
    $c = array_intersect($a, array($duplicate));
    $r = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($c as $k => $v) {
        $l   = ++$k - $i;
        $r[] = array_slice($a, $i, $l);
        $i   = $k;
    }

    return $r;
}

$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,0,6,7,0,8,9,10,11,12,0);

print_r(split_array_by_duplicate_values($a));
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 10
            [3] => 11
            [4] => 12
            [5] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: looks nice but when i copy paste, i have blank browser...anything wrong??

Comment: I forgot to put ``return`` statement, my bad. Could you try again?

Comment: hmm what about if my array (1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0) how to split to be (1,1,1,1,1,0) (1,1,0) (1,1,1,1,1,0)

Comment: Do you want to always split at ``0`` regardless of other duplicate values e.g. ``1``?

Comment: I've updated my answer to split by ``0`` instead. Also, pls accept the answer if it's correct.

Comment: GREAT....i think that i want...let me integrated to my system. thanx for your solution..

Comment: can u help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650447/php-split-array-from-query

Comment: yep, i'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6);

$array_0 = array_splice($array, 0, 4);
$array_1 = array_splice($array, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `array_splice`.

```
$array=array(1,2,3,0,4,5,6);
$newarray=array_splice($array,4);
print_r($array); //Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3]=>0);
print_r($newarray); //Array( [0]=>4 [1]=>5 [2]=>6)
```

If you want to split an array into two arrays in one multidimensional array, you could do

```
$array=array(1,2,3,0,4,5,6);
$newarray=array_chunk($array,4); //returns [[1,2,3,0],[4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use array split to split the array as you would like

```
<?php
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$output = array_slice($input, 2);      // returns "c", "d", and "e"
$output = array_slice($input, -2, 1);  // returns "d"
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);   // returns "a", "b", and "c"

// note the differences in the array keys
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1));
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1, true));
?>
```