# PHP - split array from query

Tags: php, arrays, split

I am using PHP and I have array from query

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [question_id] => 13
            [is_break] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [question_id] => 14
            [is_break] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [question_id] => 15
            [is_break] => 0
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [question_id] => 16
            [is_break] => 1
        )
    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [question_id] => 17
            [is_break] => 1
        )
)
```

How to split (grouping) by is_break = 1 so i have question_id (13,14)(15,16)(17)

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. It's a perfectly valid programming question and conditional grouping of array values doesn't always seem straight-forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's solution

```
$data   = {your data};

$result = array();
$i      = 0;
foreach($data as $k => $item) {

    if ($item->is_break) {
        $result[] = array_slice($data, $i, $k);
    }
    $i = $k;
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple and naive solution might look something like this:

```
var original = /* your original array, the one you posted */;
var result = [];
var tmp = [];
$.each(original, function(idx, obj) {
    tmp.push(obj.question_id);
    if(obj.is_break == 1) {
        result.push(tmp);
        tmp = [];
    }
});
console.log(result); // returns array of array
```

HTH

EDIT: In PHP, it may look something like this (I am not too well-versed in PHP):

```
var $original = /* your original array, the one you posted */;
var $result = [];
var $tmp = [];
foreach($original as $obj) {
    $tmp.push($obj.question_id); /* or could be $obj['question_id'] */
    if($obj.is_break == 1) { /* or could be $obj['is_break'] */
        $result.push($tmp);
        $tmp = [];
    }
});
```

Comment: You must then specify the language. Anyways, the logic that I presented applies to arrays in any language including PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$inputArr = Array
(
Array("question_id" => 13, "is_break" => 0),
 Array("question_id" => 14, "is_break" => 1),
 Array("question_id" => 15, "is_break" => 0),
 Array("question_id" => 16, "is_break" => 1),
 Array("question_id" => 17, "is_break" => 1)
);

$result = array();
$tmp = array();

foreach ($inputArr as $obj) {
    //$tmp . push($obj . question_id); /* or could be $obj['question_id'] */

    array_push($tmp, $obj['question_id']);

    if ($obj['is_break'] == 1) { /* or could be $obj['is_break'] */
        //$result . push($tmp);
        array_push($result, $tmp);
        $tmp = array();
    }
}

var_dump($result);
?>
```

- Thanks